# Cannot insert null into datetime in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I am trying to insert null with my query into a datetime column which allows null. My query works fine (I think). But its putting 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 instead of null into the datetime column. Why is this happening and how do I fix it ?

I created my own table to test this and nulling is NOT a problem there. But, it is a problem in another database. I think it must be something to do with the other database.

Comment: I looked here - http://forums.asp.net/t/1687805.aspx but there seems to be no clear answer.

Comment: Can you show us the code you are using to put data into the datetime column?  The schema of the table would be helpful as well.

Comment: show us your query pls

Comment: Check if default value is not defined on table/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see all the triggers in the database, use the following query:

```
select 
    t.name as [TableName], 
    tr.name as [TriggerName], 
    m.[definition]
from sys.triggers tr
join sys.sql_modules m on m.object_id = tr.object_id
join sys.tables t on t.object_id = tr.parent_id
```

To see all the default constraints, use the following query:

```
select 
    t.name as [TableName],  
    c.name as [ColumnName], 
    dc.[name] as [ConstraintName], 
    dc.[definition] 
from sys.tables t
join sys.columns c on c.object_id = t.object_id
join sys.objects do on do.object_id = c.default_object_id
join sys.default_constraints dc on dc.object_id= do.object_id
```

Comment: Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 'sys.triggers'.
Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 'sys.sql_modules'.
Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 'sys.tables'.

Comment: Those are all standard SQL Server Object Catalog views (see [this article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189783(v=sql.105).aspx) in MSDN for more details). If you can't see them, you'll probably have to ask your DBA why not.

Comment: Muhammad ali's answer works - select Name, OBJECT_NAME(parent_obj) FROM sysobjects where xtype = 'TR'

Comment: Yes, [sysobjects](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177596%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) is one of the backward-compatibility views; note that according to Microsoft, "This feature will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server."

Answer (score 2):

When inserting using INSERT query, don't specify the column name and don't give any value. That should insert null in the field.

For example, If `Entry_Date` is my nullable datetime column in `abc` table, then my insert statement would be like:

```
Insert into abc (Entry_Id, Entry_Value) values (1,1000);
```

By not mentioning the column, it should have null in it. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

If your insert statement is O.K., then the only reason would be a trigger that alters the value of the insert. (Providing there isn't a bug on your SQL Server. :-) )

So check if your table you're inserting into does have triggers and what they do.

To see the list of triggers either select from sys.triggers in the DB where is the table or in SQL Server Management Studio in the Object Explorer go to the table and then expand it / Triggers - then you can check each trigger. You need to check INSTEAD OF triggers. But you might have a look also onto AFTER triggers if INSTEAD OF triggers don't cause this.

The other option is that the insert statement has a bug and the column defaults to 1900. In that case, are you sure you insert into the column you want ? Do you use INSERT Table(List of columns) Values and the order of columns and order of values is correct ?

Comment: I am inserting to the correct table, with correct list of columns. How do I check for triggers and specifically the one that might be causing this problem ?

Comment: Updated the answer. Note that INSERTED in the trigger is a special table that has the rows that will be inserted into the table.

Comment: select Name, OBJECT_NAME(parent_obj) FROM sysobjects where xtype = 'TR' query to check if there are any triggers on a table :)

Comment: @MuhammedAli - That helps. I saw the triggers.