# How to UPDATE NULL to datetime field in SQLServer with C#

Tags: c#, database, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to update datetime data on sqlserver but `DBNull.Value` writes `1900-01-01 00:00:00.000` to my database. I want it NULL. How can I do?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19641813/cannot-insert-null-into-datetime-in-sql-server ?

Comment: I think it is about Insert query. I want to use UPDATE query.

Comment: Is your column nullable in the database?

Comment: Allow Nulls option is checked in database.